# What options do I have to seal the top of the concrete base of a galvanized steel post? Should I seal it?

Tags: concrete, fence, sealing, post

As the subject line says I am looking for options to seal the top of the concrete base of a galvanized steel post? Should I seal it?

Update: Here is what my posts look like and the specs https://www.masterhalco.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/PM-Install-TearPad-011480-English.pdf

[image]
[image]

Comment: Seal it against what, to accomplish what purpose?

Comment: Water I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A galvanized post that is "fixed" into concrete should not be an issue with regard to rust, it would probably rust on the top of the post first. But if you are concerned then the main things to consider here are:

- Can water get into the post and sit, normally there are holes drilled
  for water drainage is the galvanized coating damaged in any way.
- Normally when I handle galvanized metal,  i may grind or weld near the posts. 
  if this happens and you expose the raw metal, it will become a rust
  spot and spread over time
- Will the post separate from the concrete.This is common issue when setting a square post into the cement, its always better to have a t-piece welded to the section of post that you would set into the cement.
- Lastly, if you are concerned about pooling water around the base of the post, then its a good idea to set a slope on the cement so that there is runoff. this can be above or below ground and will work as effectively.  There is no real need 
  to seal the cement, since it is porous any way and will absorb moisture from all directions, but if you are really concerned, then you can add some additive (acrylic bonding agent) into the mix to make it more waterproof

Comment: my posts are not hollow, look for PostMaster @Lowes.ca . I am concerned with the top end of the concrete base that sticks out of the soil or I might bury it under an inch or two of soil if that is needed or recommended

Comment: The posts have some holes at the bottom side (the linked PDF shows two but there is a bigger one in the hat section (see the picture in the update) just at the bottom of the post lined up like an inch above the two  holes in the flanges. I am considering putting a piece of epoxied rebar there, not sure if I can find precut ones 10" long. It will help with extracting the post from the ground (I set them in sonotubes)

Answer (score 0):

To provide for a sealing of the surface of the concrete base you could consider using an epoxy based paint material similar to what is used for garage floors. Since it will be outside you will need to ensure that the finish you use has resistance to degradation from UV rays. It may come down to having to re-apply the finish every couple of years.

There are coatings that are made especially for tennis courts that will likely have more of the desirable properties for outdoor usage so do consider those as well.